# How to change DateTime format into another C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, format, typeof

I want to know how to change a DateTime format into another. I mean, I get a value in string that it will represent a DateTime value added into Typed DataTable, but I got an error at the moment of adding the DataRow

```
dr[i] = value;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

The column for that field was set like this.

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("CreateDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

So, I'm receiving this value "30-01-1984" and crash!!! so. Imagine that I defined now 2 datetime formats. I want to configure this format for telling to my app that I'm gonna receive this format "MM-dd-yyyy" and change it to this format "yyyy-MM-dd". So I want to parse my string value into the first format and then verify if I can change it into the new format.

Thanks

Comment: Fix your dbase table, *never* store a date as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are getting a formatted string with `DateTime` value, you have to parse it in .Net `DateTime` type object, using `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`, (or `DateTime.TryParse` variants) like:

```
string yourStringDate = "30-01-1984";
DateTime dateTimeObj = DateTime.ParseExact(yourStringDate, 
                                  "d-M-yyyy", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

*(I have used single `d` and `M` which would work for both single digit Day and Month)*

Later add that in your DataTable. like:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["CreateDate"] = dateTimeObj;
```

I am not sure how you are getting back the date as string, If you are storing `DateTime` as string in Database, then its better to use `DateTime` type provided by database, instead of keeping dates as string.

Comment: Note `d` or `M` will not match single digit day and month if they are not seperated with a delimiter

Comment: In fact, I'm receiving the value from a flat file as string and I gonna assign it as string into the respective column of the DT but the column is already added as a DateTime type so. I'm gonna set the formats into a database for telling the app to interpret as format defined. I don't understand your answer, sorry

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, Your `DataTable` column type is `DateTime`, that will only accept `DateTime` values, So when you are adding new row, then "CreateDate" column will only accept `DateTime` type value, I have also modified my answer to reflect that, I hope its clear now

Comment: @Habib, So clear right now. but one more question. If I'm receiving 31-01-1984 my format in the DateTime.Parse must be as "dd-MM-yyyy" in that way, it works. But, if I defined "yyyy-MM-dd" and I got an exception. So in order to add it to my DT first, I need to interpret the data as is and then when it's accepted I can change it to any format right?

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, yes, For parsing use the format `d-M-yyyy` and then later you can use `yyyy-MM-dd` for displaying

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do this by now and I'm still getting an error of incorrect string output. 
return DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.ParseExact(strValue, sourceFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(), outputFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
So I did this for the moment in order to continue 
return DateTime.ParseExact(strValue, sourceFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
sourceFormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy"
outputFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd"
Thanks for your answer. it was clear.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, I am not sure why you are doing the parsing twice in `DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.ParseExact(` you just have to do it once